# Column mode not working

Tags: notepad++

I extend a column selection in Notepad++ with Alt-Shift-cursor keys.
Then, when I release the Alt and Shift keys, Notepad replaces all lines in the selection with some random character

```
 Some lines of text
 Some lines of text
 Some lines of text
 Some lines of text

 SelectedColumn
 SelectedColumn
 SelectedColumn
 SelectedColumn
 SelectedColumn
 SelectedColumn
 SelectedColumn
```

Now release those two keys and I get this:

```
 Some lines of text
 Some lines of text
 Some lines of text
 Some lines of text

 N
 N
 N
 N
 N
 N
 N
```

with a blinking cursor (in this example) all the way down right to the N's, i.e. 7 rows high.

Is there a fix/workaround?

- Running version 7.5.9 64 bit under Win7 and Win 10.
- I have this on three out of three systems that I regularly use, configurations differ somewhat.
- This happens e.g. in new files or opened .txt files
- Not just with column selections starting in column 1.
- The character varies, often it's an Ä.

Comment: I can't reproduce this behaviour, V7.6.3 64-bit Windows 10

Comment: I can't reproduce this behavior either. V7.6.4, 64-bit Windows 7. It's acting like you bumped the "N" key when releasing the Alt-Shift keys. But you say it's a different character each time, so that's probably not it. Any chance you have a macro configured?

Comment: @DougDeden No, no macros other that what comes 'out of the box'. Often it's the Ä character.